Salvation by faith
The Bible says :
-"It is by grace that you are saved, by the means of faith. And it does not come from you, it is the gift of God’. (Eph 2:8). And
-"So faith comes from what we hear, and what we hear comes from the word of Christ.’ (Rom 10:17).
Can we be saved without having heard of Jesus?

Welcome to the group. Some theologians like Karl Rahner speak of "anonymous Christians" who have responded to God's grace without hearing of Jesus.

By the way to avoid having your question closed as "opinion based" you might want to phrase it differently such as "what are the arguments in favor of the proposition that we can be saved with hearing of Jesus?" I realize this may feel like nit-picking but that's how the culture of our group has developed.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Here is the rephrased question: "According to the passages of the Bible quoted (Ephesians 2:8 and Romans 10:17), faith and grace are necessary for salvation. However, these passages also emphasize the importance of hearing the word of Christ. In this context, is it possible to be saved without having heard of Jesus?''

There is one name given among men, under heaven, whereby we must be saved. Acts 4:12.
